# Executor Service framework with consumer code

Tags: java

I am planning to write code that's similar to producer and consumer using `ExecutorService`  with a fixed threadpool and IBM MQ messaging.

Suppose as consumer I created 10 fixed threads. How it will handle it if I place 10 messages in consumer queue? How 10 consumer worker threads will cover below scenarios?

1. each worker thread take single message synchronously and process the message?
2. each consumer worker threads  take all these 10 message like 1 worker thread per one message?
3. After reading this message as second scenario above ,How each thread call executor service.Is it done concurrenly or synchronously.
4. if there are 20 messages in queue,how consumer worker thread takes these message,each thread takes 2 messages? If it takes one message per one thread what will happen to 
   other 10 messages?

While processing the above scenarios there is webservice call and internal api method calls but those are  synchronous methods. So is there any use if i implement this class to process the code concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to implement producer/consumer scheme when you have good tools like [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) already implemented, debugged, support many features and supported by frameworks (like Spring for instance).

Don't invent the wheel!

Comment: Do you mean Spring with JMS?.How without consumer Spring JMS will read messages concurrently?.My application is component based.so it wont run on any application server.

Comment: @user2680017 JMS is not tied to Spring or any other framework, and of course it supports concurrency! It can be used with Java EE but doesn't REQUIRE it.

Comment: Here my problem is after reading the message,based on data i have to make webservice call to retrieve data.and prepare the message again with that data and send it to the new queue.is it all possible with spring,jms without using concurrency package from java

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you're asking: JMS takes care of concurrency for you. Once you removed a message from the queue - no there's only one agent that handles it and once it has been inserted into the new queue JMS takes care about concurrency again.

Comment: Thanks alfasin: I read some of the tutorials and all taling about JMS template.In JMStemplate i dont see anywhere to take the properties channel,host name,port,queuename ,queuemanager ,open options and get options.SO how to build my own jms template based on these properties.

Comment: i will open new question

Answer (score 3):

If you're running in an application server, like WebSphere for example, then you can simply deploy a Message Driven Bean (MDB) onto the JMS queue, and it will do pretty much exactly what you're describing.

If you're just building a Java application, then using the ExecutorService would work. Start by placing a MessageListener onto the Session, and have the onMessage() of that listener submit() a processor (e.g. a Runnable) of the message to the ExecutorService. Once that processor has done its work, it should acknowledge() the message.

Comment: If implemented by ExecutorService then why to implement MessageListener and onMessage methods.Please provide any examples if you have it.

Comment: Someone needs to listen to the messages coming in. Either you are blocking on the message queue waiting for a message, or you or polling (repeatedly asking) the message queue for a message in a non-blocking manner, or you are letting the message queue push a message to you (the MessageListener.onMessage approach). Think of it like trying to buy something that a store is out of -- you can go into the store and wait for the item to arrive, or you can drop by every two minutes to see if they got some in, or you can ask them to send you one as soon as they receive it.